# Trying to download the pdf from internet and not getting the full file

Tags: java, android-studio, inputstream, httpurlconnection, fileinputstream

I want to download a pdf file from a url and show that file in pdf reader but always its just reading 236 bytes and when i open the file, it shows that pdf format is not valid.

pdfActivty.java

```
package com.example.mudasir.login.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mudasir.login.FileDownloader;
import com.example.mudasir.login.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PdfActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void download(View v){
        new DownloadFile().execute("http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf","maven.pdf");
    }

    public void view(View v)
    {
        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testthreepdf/" + "maven.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try{
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(PdfActivity.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
            folder.mkdir();

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

            try{
                pdfFile.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

FileDownloader.java

```
package com.example.mudasir.login;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by mudasir on 9/27/2016.
 */
public class FileDownloader {
    private static final int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = -1;
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
               fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mudasir.login">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signin_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SideMenuActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PdfActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pdf"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? Does it load a PDF file if you use it in a browser?

Comment: Yeah URL is absolutely correct.. It downloads 928 KB file.

Comment: It stores the file in device internal storage but the file is og just 237 bytes.

Comment: If you had a look at the content download file you would have seen the problem: The content is HTML which tells you that the file location has been moved. Browsers can read such information an redirect to the new URL. Either you use the correct URL or implement own logic to parse such an answer

Comment: So mean to say the link is faulty..??

Comment: Code logic is fine..??